# jQuery :empty not working with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having a problem in using jQuery's :empty pseudo selector. Basically, it isn't working on inputs the way I think it should. Given this html, I'm trying to get a count of all the inputs which don't have values without a loop.

```
<div id="sampleDiv">
<label>My first Input:</label>
<input name="test" id="firstInput" type="text" value="default text" /><br/><br/>
<label>My second Input:</label>
<input name="test" id="secondInput" type="text" value="" /><br/><br/>
<label>My third Input:</label>
<input name="test" id="thirdInput" type="text" value="" />
```

I'm using a selector like this

```
$('#sampleDiv input:empty').length
```

but it's returning 3, including the one with the value. Here is the fiddle and thanks for any help here!:
https://jsfiddle.net/chas688/b5fad3Lu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:empty` selector is designed to look through the children of an element. This is why it doesn't necessarily work for you in this instance. Instead, you can select by the `value` attribute:

```
$('#sampleDiv input[value=""]').length;
```

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b5fad3Lu/3/)

Or by `filter()`:

```
$('#sampleDiv input').filter(function() {
    return this.value == '';
}).length;
```

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b5fad3Lu/4/)

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks - I even copied and pasted that. Not sure how I messed it up, lol.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense now, it was a bit misleading on the W3c selectors reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Note that W3Schools has *nothing* to do with the W3C and are a bunch of..... See http://w3fools.com for more info. I'd suggest never using their site.

Comment: Also, glad to help :)

Comment: Lol, I'll check that out. I like the filter version better since I don't know if the value attribute will always be set, even. I'll check this answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: W3Schools even uses `$("input:not(:empty)")` in their example on how to use `:not`. I guess they missed a *not* somewhere in there.

Comment: Sounds about right for them, misleading information everywhere. @chas688 if you want a reference for jQuery, use http://api.jquery.com. It's kept up to date by the devs themselves.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for the link too. I had bookmarked that selector thing years ago, so i can see it's now quite outdated and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The `:empty` stands for empty HTML and not empty values! You have to use this way:

```
count = 0;
$('#sampleDiv input').each(function () {
  if ($(this).val().length == 0)
    count++;
});
```

Or use `.filter()`:

```
$('#sampleDiv input').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).val().trim().length == 0);
}).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for all input text.
https://jsfiddle.net/b5fad3Lu/2/

```
var pl = $('input:text[value=""]').length;
$('#numberofEmpty').text( pl );
```